# Flow screen component "Phone" field can not be assign to invocable variable

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, invocable-method

I have created flow and in this flow screen I have phone field.
[image]

however, I cannot assign the value from this field to invocable variable.
I do not see "Phone" in the dropdown list in invoacble variable.

[image]

In Apex class I have

```
@InvocableVariable
public String mobilephone;
@InvocableVariable
public String homephone;
```

For Phone field in screen components values :

[image]

What am I doing wrong here? I tried assigning Text data type variable in "Store Output Value" - Value feild.. and map that variable to Invocable variable. but I get null value everytime.

Comment: got a solution for this?

Comment: @Thomas I ended up using Text field for phone number with REGEX in input validation. However if you don't worry about international phone format, then in phone field in flow you need to create Text type variable resource in flow and assign it to **Store Output Values** --> Value. And use that text variable to bind to your invocable variable.